# How can I get slot in Demandware Script?

Tags: configuration, getcontent, commerce-cloud

There is one method by which we can access content slot in demandware, that is by using `<isslot>` tag in the template, but is there any other way by which we can do that?

I mean by using demandware script, instead of using the `<isslot>` tag. We can get almost every other feature like content asset, image etc. But can we get `slot` configuration by using demandware script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Slot configurations are not accessible via the Script API. Even within the context of a rendering template used *within* a slot you can't access all the details of that slot configuration. However, you can access slot configurations using the OCAPI Data API. That said, it wouldn't be helpful within the context of a storefront session.